# How to define multiple xorg screens using the same device?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, graphics, multiple-monitors, adapter

I have a video-adapter(Dell MMH11) that is connected to the display-port of my graphics card. The adapter identifies itself to the graphics card as a 3840x1200 display. 
The adapter has two monitors connected to it (monitor resolution=1920x1200).
A third monitor is connected directly on the graphics card DVI port(same resolution). 
So I have 3 monitors, but xorg only recognizes 2 "monitors" {adapter(3840*1200), samsung(1920x1200)}. 
I have these two "monitors" configured in xorg.conf with the nvidia driver and using Xanorama.

The window manager (KDE in my case) runs just fine. However, the it recognizes just two screens, which breaks stuff like full-screen functionality (now it's not full-screen but two-full-screen). Also, window snapping is 'wrong' and the menu is crossing the two screens.

Does X11/xorg.conf provide a way to 'split' a monitor+device into two screens? So is it possible to create two screen sections that are using the same device (the MMH11 adapter). I assume that KDE will get will get the displays right that way. (Just like it picks up the borders/size for the adapter and the direct monitor at this time, from the current screen sections.)